# Mathematica 10.2 Notebooks Freezing

Tags: windows

I've been having a problem with notebooks in Mathematica 10.2 freezing up on my Windows 8.1 laptop.  It seems to happen when I am typing input.  The notebook freezes (become unresponsive) for 30 secs or so, sometimes it resolves but often Window reports "Mathematica 10.2 not responding" and closes Mathematica.  The laptop is only a couple months old and should have plenty of RAM (8 GB) for what I am doing.  I don't have this problem with Mathematica 10 on my Windows 7 machine.  Anyone else have this problem?  Any fixes?